# struct.unpack returning very large value python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, struct, unpack

I feel like this should be simple, and because it's so simple, I can't wrap my head around why it's not working.

I have a basic function that uses struct.unpack to turn a bytearray into an integer. So we can see that in hex notation x90 = 144 in decimal. So I would expect that if I ask unpack to convert to integer, I get 144, but I'm getting this ridiculously large number. I'm happy to read whatever reference material you can provide, as the [struct documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) does not provide any clues.

See example below:

```
unpack_signed_integer, = struct.unpack('i', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')
unpack_unsigned_integer, = struct.unpack('I', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')

print(f"signed integer: {unpack_signed_integer}")
print(f"unsigned integer: {unpack_unsigned_integer}")
```

Output:

```
signed integer: -1879048192
unsigned integer: 2415919104
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are unpacking the value 0x90_00_00_00, that is, a 64 bit number in little-endian order. It is large because it has 7 hexadecimal zeros, each representing a power of sixteen.

Either reverse the order of your bytes, or [pick a different byte order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

```py
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('I', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')
(2415919104,)
>>> struct.unpack('I', b'\x90\x00\x00\x00')
(144,)
>>> struct.unpack('>I', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')
(144,)
```

In the above example, the `>` in `'>I'` tells `struct.unpack()` to use big-endian ordering instead. If you are dealing with data you received from some network protocol, you should probably use `!` instead, which represents the default byte order for network communications as per the [IETF RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700); this is the same as `>` big-endian order, but codified to avoid confusion.

Without an explicit byte order marker, `@`, or *native* byte order, is assumed. In your specific case, your machine native byte order is little-endian, but that is a property of the specific machine architecture of your computer, not of Python.

Comment: Damn. That's it! See I knew it was simple, I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

The formats `'i'` and `'I'` are using your machine's native byte order, which in this case is little-endian. You can be explicit about what [endianness you want to use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

```
>>> struct.unpack('i', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')  # native, implicit
(-1879048192,)
>>> struct.unpack('@i', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')  # native, explicit
(-1879048192,)
>>> struct.unpack('<i', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')  # explicitly little-endian
(-1879048192,)
>>> struct.unpack('>i', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')  # explicitly big-endian
(144,)
>>> struct.unpack('!i', b'\x00\x00\x00\x90')  # explicitly network order
(144,)
```

Network protocols use big-endian as a machine-independent ordering.